# How To Create Flashing Frames - [tkinter]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been struggling with getting two frames to flash after `x` amount of time for many hours and I am really unsure what to do. I have looked into `.sleep` as well as `.after`. No matter how I try to get this to work it will always just wait `x` amount of time then show the frame I want to show. The outcome that I would like should look like this: https://multiplesclerosis.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/33518_custom.gif.

Any help would be amazing.

```
class DataPage(tk.Frame, tk.Tk):
... (non-important methods)
    def vepSlideShow(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("P300")
        root.state("zoomed")
        container = tk.Frame(root)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        frames = {}

        frames[WBChecker] = WBChecker(container, root)
        frames[WBChecker].grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        frames[BWChecker] = BWChecker(container, root)
        frames[BWChecker].grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")


        def test():
            print("Hit")
            currentwin = frames[BWChecker]
            nextwin = frames[BWChecker] if currentwin == frames[BWChecker] else frames[BWChecker]
            root.after(5000, test())

        test()
        root.mainloop()


    def changeWindow(self, frame1, frame2):
        print("Hit")
        frame1.after(5000, frame1.tkraise())


class WBChecker(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        canvas.config(height=1080, width=1920)
        canvas.pack()
        SIZE=126
        color = 'white'

        for y in range(8):

            for x in range(16):
                x1 = x*SIZE
                y1 = y*SIZE
                x2 = x1 + SIZE
                y2 = y1 + SIZE
                canvas.create_rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill=color)
                if color == 'white':
                    color = 'black'
                else:
                    color = 'white'

            if color == 'white':
                color = 'black'
            else:
                color = 'white'

class BWChecker(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        canvas2 = tk.Canvas(self)
        canvas2.config(height=1080, width=1920)
        canvas2.pack()

        SIZE=126
        color = 'black'

        for y in range(8):

            for x in range(16):
                x1 = x*SIZE
                y1 = y*SIZE
                x2 = x1 + SIZE
                y2 = y1 + SIZE
                canvas2.create_rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill=color)
                if color == 'white':
                    color = 'black'
                else:
                    color = 'white'

            if color == 'white':
                color = 'black'
            else:
                color = 'white'
    def vepSlideShow(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("P300")
        root.state("zoomed")
        container = tk.Frame(root)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        frames = {}

        frames[WBChecker] = WBChecker(container, root)
        frames[WBChecker].grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        frames[BWChecker] = BWChecker(container, root)
        frames[BWChecker].grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")


        def test():
            print("Hit")
            currentwin = frames[BWChecker]
            nextwin = frames[BWChecker] if currentwin == frames[BWChecker] else frames[BWChecker]
            root.after(5000, test())

        test()
        root.mainloop()


    def changeWindow(self, frame1, frame2):
        print("Hit")
        frame1.after(5000, frame1.tkraise())


class WBChecker(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        canvas.config(height=1080, width=1920)
        canvas.pack()
        SIZE=126
        color = 'white'

        for y in range(8):

            for x in range(16):
                x1 = x*SIZE
                y1 = y*SIZE
                x2 = x1 + SIZE
                y2 = y1 + SIZE
                canvas.create_rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill=color)
                if color == 'white':
                    color = 'black'
                else:
                    color = 'white'

            if color == 'white':
                color = 'black'
            else:
                color = 'white'

class BWChecker(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        canvas2 = tk.Canvas(self)
        canvas2.config(height=1080, width=1920)
        canvas2.pack()

        SIZE=126
        color = 'black'

        for y in range(8):

            for x in range(16):
                x1 = x*SIZE
                y1 = y*SIZE
                x2 = x1 + SIZE
                y2 = y1 + SIZE
                canvas2.create_rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill=color)
                if color == 'white':
                    color = 'black'
                else:
                    color = 'white'

            if color == 'white':
                color = 'black'
            else:
                color = 'white'
```

Comment: `after` should be given a _reference_ to a function.

Comment: So I have already tried using it as a reference but it seems to have the same outcome. It will wait for `x` amount of time and then `tkraise()` the correct frame. I have done things such as:
        `#root.after(5000, test())`
        `#frames[BWChecker].after(5000, test())`
       `#container.after(5000, test())`
with only `            frames[BWChecker].tkraise()` in the function.

Comment: Those examples don't include a reference. You are immediately calling `test()` and passing the result to `after`. It should be `root.after(5000, test)`. Notice the lack of `()` after `test`

Comment: Amazing! That seemed to be the issue. I have been trying to get this to work for the last 7 hours. I can't believe it was that simple , Thank you so much!